# How to remove last character of last row in tmap using Talend?

Tags: database, integration, talend, tmap

I am extracting two columns using `textractjson` and passing it to a `tmap` component where I am concatenating both of the columns as single one.

Also, I want a comma at the end of each row except the last row.

I am not sure how to do this.

**Example:**

There are two columns in `tmap` as input:

1. `FirstName`
2. `LastName`

In output, I have concatenated them to:

```
FirstName+LastName+","
```

The problem is I dont want the comma in the last row.

Comment: What is the use of this output ? Is it for a CSV file ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your job layout and input structure.

You seem to use `tExtractJSON`, which could mean you get the data from a REST call or out of a database.

Since there is no fixed row amount because of the JSON data structure, you wouldn't be able to use `((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileInputDelimited_1_NB_LINE"))`. Again, since we don't know your job layout, this depends on it.

If this is not the case, I would count the rows in a `tJavaRow` component first and then add a second `tJavaRow` where I'd concat the strings (wouldn't do that in the tMap), but omit the last comma. I'd be able to find the last row with the count I did first. This depends on your Java skills.

Answer (score 1):

You may also concatenate all the rows in a global variable using a tJavaRow, with a comma at the end for each row.
Then, start a new subjob (onSubjobOk) then using a tJava, remove the last character (so the last comma).
Pretty simple, don't have to know how many rows from the input flow but supposing you want the result as a single string (here contained in a global variable).

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong also. Basically concatenate FirstName and LastName , Create record number column using **Numeric.Sequence()** function and use one more context variable and store the same sequence number here(it might store last value) also in **tJavaRow** component.

```
output_row.name = input_row.FirstName+""+input_row.LastName+","+;
output_row.record_number = Numeric.sequence("recNo", 1, 1);
context.lastNumber = Numeric.sequence("recNo", 1, 1);
```

create a method in custom java routine.

```
public static string main _nameChange(String name,Integer record_number){
if(context.lastNumber == record_number){
name = name.substring(0,name.length()-1);
return name;
}
else{
return name;
}
}
```

Now call **_nameChange** method within **tmap** component. Now you can trim the last row's last character.
Ror reference  [check this](http://www.vikramtakkar.com/2013/07/fetch-last-record-from-fileflow-in.html)